# Fake proof that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{x^3}=\frac{-9}{2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, fake-proofs

In the book Mathematical Fallacies, Flaws, and Flimflam, the following fake proof is provided:

[image]

The question starts with using trigonometric identities to turn $\sin(3x)\to3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$. Then divides the limit into two where the limit of $({\frac{\sin(x)}{x}})^3$ is obviously $1$, and variable substitutes $x=3t$ making $\frac{\sin(3t)}{(3t)^3}$ which can then be manipulated to become the original equation of $\frac{\sin(3x)}{x^3}$, giving a final result of $-9/2$.

I fail to see where the error is in the calculations, everything seems sound, but I know through the use of L'Hôpital's rule and Desmos that the answer should be $\infty$ at $x=0$.

Comment: It's also true, in a loosey-goosey sort of way, that $\infty = \frac{\infty}{9}-4$. So you could argue that they simply haven't considered all the "solutions." But I think the "righter" way to think of it is that "limit of sum is sum of limits" requires that the component limits exist, as others have pointed out.

Comment: What they proved is that *if* the limit exists and is finite then it must be $-9/2$.

Comment: @BrianTung Well, “the limit exists” may to taken to include infinite limits, as long a you don’t get $\infty - \infty$. In this view, splitting up the limits is valid for the reason you gave, but moving one $L(=\infty)$ to the other side is not, as that yields $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: @Gary Could it be possible $\frac{\sin(3t)}{t^3}$ is not actually equivalent to the original equation $L$, and that to make it L we would have to substitute x=3t to get the fraction in terms of x giving $$\frac{\sin(x)}{(\frac{x}{3})^3}$$ which is obviously not equal to the original equation $L=\frac{\sin3x}{x^3}$

Comment: @MPK1962 It is the same limit. You can call $t$ anything you like. $L=\sin(3x)/x^3$ is not correct since $L$ is the *limit* of that quotient (if exists). In addition, the limit of $\sin(x)/(x/3)^3$ is again $L$ (provided it exists).